# Const array parameter change its value

Tags: javascript

Why this happens:

```
const arr = ["a", "b","c"];

const functionA = (arr) => {
   arr='banana'
};

const functionB = (arr) => {
    arr.push('d');
};

const functionC = (arr) => {
    arr.shift();
};

functionA(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // displays ["a","b","c"]

functionB(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // displays ["a","b","c","d"]

functionC(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // displays ["b","c","d"]
```

arr is a const and functions modifies it inside the scope
I guess it is cause the arr param is a reference to the original and changes on it results in the original being changed.

What would be the best way to declare those functions to avoid this behavior? eg. displays ["a","b","c"]

Comment: If you don't want the function modifying your original array, don't pass it your original array. Pass a copy: `functionA([...arr])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original array, then there's an easy solution here:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b","c"];

const functionA = (arr) => {
  return [ 'banana' ];
};

const functionB = (arr) => {
  return [ ...arr, 'd' ];
};

const functionC = (arr) => {
  let copy = [ ...arr ];
  copy.shift();
  
  return copy;
};

console.log(`functionA(arr)=${JSON.stringify(functionA(arr))}`);
console.log(`functionB(arr)=${JSON.stringify(functionB(arr))}`);
console.log(`functionC(arr)=${JSON.stringify(functionC(arr))}`);

console.log(`arr=${JSON.stringify(arr)}`);
```

This code reassigns the *variable*, not the reference:

```js
const functionA = (arr) => {
   arr = 'banana';
};
```

What you need to do is preserve that reference, as in:

```
const functionA = (arr) => {
   arr.splice(0, arr.length, 'banana');
};
```

Comment: actually that function is the only one that works for me. What I need is the other two NOT changing the original value.

Comment: If you want to preserve the array as-is, you **must not** use any functions that could potentially alter it, like `pop()` or `shift()`, or work on a copy, as in `arr = [ ...arr ]`.

Comment: How? arr2 = arr results in the same reference, changing both of them.

Comment: That's just how it is in JavaScript. Variables are effectively object references for non-primitive types such as anything but numbers or booleans. If you want a copy you *must* ask for one. If you're use to something like C++ where copy is the default, you'll need to change your expectations.

Comment: But, what will you do if you want the array remains a,b,c in this scenario?

Comment: `arr = [ ...arr ]` inside of a function just redefines that variable within the function, and only *within the function*. It has absolutely no impact on the `arr` that was passed in. You can call it something else like `let copy = [ ...arr ]` if that makes it more clear for you.

Comment: Ok, @tadman I think you shoul post it as an answer. functionB([...arr]);

Comment: Updated with non-modifying equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign another value to a `const` array. `functionA()` is assigning value to a local variable, not the reference it's pointing to.

For `functionB()` and `functionC()`, you're not changing the constant value but the array it's pointing to. So there's no problem in changing the array element.

If you want to freeze an array or object so it can't be modified, you can use the [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method.

```
const x = Object.freeze(['a'])
x.push('b')
console.log(x) // ["a"]
```

Comment: throws an error in my case. Node.js x10 (TypeError: Cannot add property 3, object is not extensible)

Comment: Yes, it will throw an error in strict mode when you're trying to modify the array.